# How do I remove the left margin of enumerate in the second level?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\currentsection}{3.5}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\currentsection.\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ohai
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item ok
  \item hi
  \end{enumerate}
\item ohai
\item ohai
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

renders

[image]

The result has a left margin. What I want is

[image]

How do I remove the left margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `align` the label to the `left`, rather than the typical right-alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\currentsection}{3.5}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\currentsection.\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item ohai
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item ok
    \item hi
    \end{enumerate}
  \item ohai
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left]
    \item ok
    \item hi
    \end{enumerate}
  \item ohai
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can I find the documentation on align?

Comment: @crocket: In the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) (p 3); or create your own alignment using `\SetLabelAlign`...

Comment: How do I prevent align=left from increasing the gap between label and text? It is confusing.

Comment: @crocket: Perhaps use `[align=left,labelsep=-0.1em,leftmargin=*]`...

Comment: labelsep=0em replicates the original gap more properly. Thanks.

Comment: Let `enumitem` do the computations for you, with `widest=a` instead of `labelsep`. The default value for this parameter is `m`.

Comment: @JavierBezos What is the difference between widest=a and widest=m?